# How to create tables with varying column number from different data.frames?

Tags: r

I have different data.frame objects with three columns. These data.frame objects are called Experiment1, Experiment2, Experiment3 ... Experiment{n} (where n is NumberTubes divided by NumberParameters).

Experiment1:

```
                                         Name          Statistic NoCells                                             
1                                        CD4 subset      41.2   11935
2                            CD4 subset/CD39 subset      30.6    3656
3                            CD4 subset/CD69 subset      4.93     588
4                            CD4 subset/CD73 subset      49.8    5946
5                           CD4 subset/CD103 subset      2.62     313
6                     CD4 subset/integrin B7 subset      4.37     521
7                                      CD8a subset      33.5    9697
8                          CD8a subset/CD39 subset      54.3    5270
9                          CD8a subset/CD69 subset      5.48     531
10                          CD8a subset/CD73 subset      73.7    7148
11                        CD8a subset/CD103 subset      4.06     394
```

Experiment2:

```
                                         Name          Statistic NoCells                                             
1                                        CD4 subset      31.1   11935
2                            CD4 subset/CD39 subset      24.6    3656
3                            CD4 subset/CD69 subset      9.91     588
4                            CD4 subset/CD73 subset      45.1    5946
5                           CD4 subset/CD103 subset      2.61     313
6                     CD4 subset/integrin B7 subset      4.34     521
7                                      CD8a subset      33.2    9697
8                          CD8a subset/CD39 subset      84.3    5270
9                          CD8a subset/CD69 subset      2.48     531
10                          CD8a subset/CD73 subset      70.7    7148
11                        CD8a subset/CD103 subset      4.01     394
```

Now I want to merge from each data.frame object the .$Statistic column in a table. The number of columns for each table should be defined by the  `NumberRepeats` variable.

For example, assume NumberRepeats = 3:

```
tab_1 <- cbind(Experiment1, Experiment2$Statistic, Experiment3$Statistic)
tab_2 <- cbind(Experiment4, Experiment5$Statistic, Experiment6$Statistic) 
....
tab_x <- cbind(Experimentn-2, Experimentn-1$Statistic, Experimentn$Statistic)
```

Another example, assume NumberRepeats = 4:

```
tab_1 <- cbind(Experiment1, Experiment2$Statistic, Experiment3$Statistic, Experiment4$Statistic)
tab_2 <- cbind(Experiment5, Experiment6$Statistic, Experiment7$Statistic, Experiment8$Statistic) 
....
tab_x <- cbind(Experimentn-3, Experimentn-2$Statistic, Experimentn-1$Statistic, Experimentn$Statistic)
```

How can this be achieved? The script should give the same output that the above cbind would, but automated based on the value of NumberRepeats and n ( NumberTubes divided by NumberParameters).

ExperimentalDesign:

```
  parameter repeat1 repeat2 repeat3
1  but       10.0   4.0  3.00
2  hip         4.0   3.0  2.00
3  H2S         0.2   0.1  0.05
4  pro          4.0   3.0  1.00
5  ace          5.0   4.0  3.00
```

Desired table_1 from loop:

```
                             name  exp1 exp2  exp3  parameter
1                      CD4 subset  41.2 31.1 ...       but
2          CD4 subset/CD39 subset  30.6 24.6  ...      but
```

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to achieve. Also, there is missing information, What are the columns names? , What is the column $Statistic? NumberRepeats, ... Please explain whit additional details

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Are the subsets Experiment1, Experiment2, etc disjoint? i.e. do they form a partition of the original data frame?

Comment: They are non-overlapping (no elements in common) and each consist of the same number of rows (which equals NumberParameters) and columns. Another subset added to question for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

With this you merge on column of different dataframe objects to one table. You can control the number of column by the `NumberRepeats` variable. All table which are stored in a list have same number of data columns like the
`NumberRepeats` variable except the last table...by the way even it is fun to make construction like this I'm not sure if this is a good way to analyze your data.

```
# created test data
for(i in 1:17){
  Name <- letters[1:7]
  Statistic <- round(rnorm(7), 3)
  assign(paste0("Experiment",i), data.frame(Name, Statistic))
}    

# set some parameters
NumberRepeats <- 5
Experiment_n <- 17
skipTube <- c(3,7,11)
```

# lets go

```
out <- list()
list_index <- 1
counter <- 1
while(counter < Experiment_n) {

  tab <- NULL
  nam <- NULL
  while((is.null(tab) || ncol(tab) < NumberRepeats) & Experiment_n >= counter){
    if(!any(counter == skipTube)){
      tab <- cbind(tab, get(paste0("Experiment", counter))$Statistic)
      # tab <- as.data.frame(tab)
      nam <- c(nam,paste0("Experiment", counter))
    }
    counter <- counter + 1  
  }
  colnames(tab) <- nam
  rownames(tab) <- as.matrix(Experiment1$Name)

  out[[list_index]] <- tab
  assign(paste0('table_', list_index), tab)

  list_index <- list_index + 1  
}
out

# get a idea for the results
p_dat <- sapply(out, function(x) rowMeans(x))
barplot(t(p_dat), beside=T)
```

Comment: this is what you want?

Comment: Thank you for the solution, this answered the question. As an aside, any comment on how this code may be adjusted to skip user-specified tubes? For example, if tube 3 is to be skipped, the first data.frame would be the result of `cbind(Experiment1, Experiment2$Statistic, Experiment4$Statistic)` (assuming NoRepeats = 3)

Comment: Re: even it is fun to make construction like this I'm not sure if this is a good way to analyze your data.

There is a much simpler solution directly from the .csv that I have, which does not require any subsetting. I chose this approach as I needed all these individual data.frames. The script prints the data in real time from the instrument allowing optimisation

Comment: now you can skip some Experiments...your data are in several csv-files? but why you create the table not immediately when you read the file and make the step with this Experiment_n dataframes...anyway when its necessary, its your way.

Comment: Thank you for your support and-bri, I am still getting to grips with R in general as an old colleague wrote many scripts which I use constantly without thinking too much. Although not required here, how would I save each tab as a variable e.g. table1, table2, table3, table4... rather than using the out?

Comment: what you do after with the table1,....? you plot information from it to get an overview? or you make some calculation with them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153818/discussion-between-and-bri-and-j-throat).

Comment: Both. At present I am in the learning phase, so I am not so concerned at present regarding the 'best' approach

Answer (score 1):

```
# created test data
for(i in 1:17){
  Name <- letters[1:7]
  Statistic <- round(rnorm(7), 3)
  assign(paste0("Experiment",i), data.frame(Name, Statistic))
}    


# create the other data
dat2 <- c(10.0,   4.0,  3.00,
4.0,   3.0,  2.00,
0.2,   0.1,  0.05,
4.0,   3.0,  1.00,
5.0,   4.0,  3.00)

dat2 <- matrix(dat2, byrow=T, ncol=3 )
colnames(dat2) <- c('conc1', 'conc2', 'conc3')
rownames(dat2) <- c('but', 'hip', 'H2S', 'pro', 'ace')


# set some parameters
NumberRepeats <- 3
Experiment_n <- 17
skipTube <- c(3,7,11)

# lets go
out <- list()
list_index <- 1
counter <- 1
while(counter < Experiment_n) {

  tab <- NULL
  nam <- NULL
  while((is.null(tab) || ncol(tab) < NumberRepeats) & Experiment_n >= counter){
    if(!any(counter == skipTube)){
      tab <- cbind(tab, get(paste0("Experiment", counter))$Statistic)
      tab <- as.data.frame(tab)
      nam <- c(nam,paste0("repeat", counter))
    }
    counter <- counter + 1  
  }
  nam[1:3] <- dat2[list_index,]
  colnames(tab) <- nam
  rownames(tab) <- as.matrix(Experiment1$Name)
  parameter <- rownames(dat2)[list_index]
  tab <- cbind(tab, parameter)

  out[[list_index]] <- tab
  assign(paste0('table_', list_index), tab)

  list_index <- list_index + 1  
}
table_1
table_2
table_3


p_dat <- sapply(out, function(x) rowMeans(x))
barplot(t(p_dat), beside=T)
```

Comment: When you updated the question, I have no ideas where the values came from for Desired table_1 from loop, Desired table_2 from loop, Desired table_3 from loop. It is not what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using loops.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

# make a list from all Experiment tables
df_list <- lapply(ls(pattern = 'Experiment'), get)
tables_index <- seq_len(length(ls(pattern = 'Experiment')))

# set NumberRepeats value
NumberRepeats <- 1

# create index for cbind function
subset_index <- rep(seq_len(length(ls(pattern = 'Experiment'))/NumberRepeats), each = NumberRepeats, length.out = length(ls(pattern = 'Experiment')))

# loops for binding needed columns
experiment_list = list()
for (i in (1:(length(ls(pattern = 'Experiment'))/NumberRepeats))) {
  indices <- tables_index[subset_index == i]
  experiment_df <- data.frame(df_list[indices[1]])
  for (j in indices[-1]) {
    experiment_df <- cbind(experiment_df, df_list[[j]]['wt'])
  }
  experiment_list[[i]] <- experiment_df
}

# show result
experiment_list
```

For me, the best way to operate with and aggregate similar columns is to unite all tables in one data.frame and then group by different parameters.